# Vectorize 2d convolution on matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, vectorization, convolution

I got this Code for computing two dimensional convolution for two given arrays.

```
[r,c] = size(x);
[m,n] = size(y);
h = rot90(y, 2);
center = floor((size(h)+1)/2);
Rep = zeros(r + m*2-2, c + n*2-2);
return

for x1 = m : m+r-1
for y1 = n : n+r-1
    Rep(x1,y1) = x(x1-m+1, y1-n+1);
end
end

B = zeros(r+m-1,n+c-1);
for x1 = 1 : r+m-1
for y1 = 1 : n+c-1
    for i = 1 : m
        for j = 1 : n
            B(x1, y1) = B(x1, y1) + (Rep(x1+i-1, y1+j-1) * h(i, j));
        end
    end
end
end
```

How can i vectorize it , so no for loops exist ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this different from your [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665895/vectorization-of-nested-for-loop-in-matlab)?

Comment: In previous post i tried to be more general and not show all of the code.

Comment: Please do not open duplicate questions. If you want to clarify something, edit the new information into the existing question.

Comment: ok. I 'll remove previous question.Do you have an idea of how this vectorisation can be implemented?

Comment: No, because you still haven't answered the question about what functions you can and can't use, and why. That's why it would have been better to delete this question, because now we have to start over again. So, why don't you just use `conv2`? :)

Comment: Are you allowed to use any functions from the image processing toolbox?

Comment: Yes.Except conv2 and everything that has to do with convolution.Other functions are welcome

Comment: And that first loop is just padding the input array with zeros, right? I'm not sure I understand your math there. For the second loop we can use `im2col`. I'll get that part working and check my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
%// generate test matrices
x = randi(12, 4, 5)
y = [2 2 2;
     2 0 2;
     2 2 2]

[r,c] = size(x);
%[m,n] = size(y);   %// didn't use this
h = rot90(y, 2);
center = floor((size(h)+1)/2);

Rep = zeros(size(x)+size(h)-1);                             %// create image of zeros big enough to pad x
Rep(center(1):center(1)+r-1, center(2):center(2)+c-1) = x;  %// and copy x into the middle

%// all of this can be compressed onto one line, if desired
%// I'm just breaking it out into steps for clarity
CRep = im2col(Rep, size(h), 'sliding');   %// 'sliding' is the default, but just to be explicit
k = h(:);                                 %// turn h into a column vector
BRow = bsxfun(@times, CRep, k);           %// multiply k times each column of CRep
B = reshape(sum(BRow), r, c)              %// take the sum of each column and reshape to match x

T = conv2(Rep, h, 'valid')                %// take the convolution using conv2 to check

assert(isequal(B, T), 'Result did not match conv2.');
```

Here are the results of a sample run:

```
x =

   11   12   11    2    8
    5    9    2    3    2
    7    9    3    4    8
    7   10    8    5    4

y =

   2   2   2
   2   0   2
   2   2   2

B =

    52    76    56    52    14
    96   120   106    80    50
    80   102   100    70    36
    52    68    62    54    34

T =

    52    76    56    52    14
    96   120   106    80    50
    80   102   100    70    36
    52    68    62    54    34
```